# Unable to access www.domain1.com but able to access sub1.domain1.com

Tags: java, google-app-engine, dns, google-apps

Somehow managed to set up custom domain name with google app engine after lots of r&d.

from [google apps cpanel](https://www.google.com/a/cpanel/domain1.com/AppEngineServiceSettings?appId=dom-hrd),

> Your users can access dom-hrd at:
>
> https://dom-hrd.appspot.com
>
> http://sub1.domain1.com

I am not able to add 'www.domain1.com' to this list, and getting error, 'Already used, please remove previous mapping first'. But, this link, 'www.domain1.com' points to google sites.

Domain 'www.domain1.com' owned by admin@domain1.com; and google appengine java application,  'dom-hrd' was deployed using my gmail id.

How to make 'http://dom-hrd.appspot.com' accessible through 'www.domain1.com'?

I have also tried renaming 'www' to 'www1' (enom > domain setting > host record > CNAME alias), and then adding 'www' through [google apps page](https://www.google.com/a/cpanel/domain1.com/AppEngineServiceSettings?appId=dom-hrd). Still, I am getting the same error, 'Already used, please remove previous mapping first'.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the CNAME records and point the **www** to **ghs.googlehosted.com**

Comment: Thanks, It has already been added. CNAME record 'www' pointing to 'ghs.google.com.'

Answer (score 0):

I did two things that fixed this issue,

> 1. Delete following web address mapping 'www.domain1.com':'www', from,
>
>    google apps > settings (tab) > services (right panel) > sites > sites settings > web address mapping
> 2. Disable google sites for my google apps domain

(3. Wait for 5 to 10 mins for changes to become visible)

Now, 'http://www.domain1.com/' is accessible and it points to 'http://dom-hrd.appspot.com/'

[This post from appengine google groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-appengine/wk0zm2QQvBQ) was helpful fixing this issue.